# Typo3 Page content not visbile in frontend

Tags: typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I have created an extension and added to a page when I executed page got a blank page. Then I inspected through view-source of browser the contents are there. but not visible.

**The view was visible on Typo3 v7 local, but not on the server.**

- I'm using the Typo3 v7 and Typo3 v8.
- Extension has been installed in both server versions, but not displaying.
- I have included the extension into the template.

> I have Checked the Debug functionality through the controller
>   that also didn't display on front-end, But is visible as source code

Should anything to be done more? Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not sound like a problem of TYPO3 than a problem with CSS.
If the HTML markup is available at the browser but not visible the browser has decided not to show it. And that probably is CSS. Use the browser debugger (firebug, inspector, ...) to identify which CSS hides the content.

Also Javascript might interact as it could change visibility after page submit. (try to load the page with deactivated javascript)

In the end it could be an additional or missing div tag or css class that is responsible and you could configure TYPO3 to change the HTML markup in the way so that your content is not hidden.

If you have one server where the content is visible and one where it is not shown you may do a diff on a page to find the difference between these servers. The HTML could be the same if CSS and/or Javascript is different.
I would save the same page from both servers localy (with all CSS and JS) and do a tree diff with a tool like [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/)